# Extract x{} from some text using REGEX

Tags: .net, regex

I need to clean some portion text like:

1. "P{    MARGIN: 0px } Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression."
2. "BODY{     MARGIN: 0px } Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression."

do you have some regex for me? Thanks in advance.

Note: For .Net desktop application using System.Text.RegularExpressions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need it for when?

Comment: What does Extract x{} from some text mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are pretty vague, but this pattern,

```
\w+\s*{.*?}
```

Will match one or more of word characters followed by an open bracket, followed by any number of whitespace characters, followed by any number of characters (non-greedily), followed by a close bracket.

For example:

```
string input = "P { MARGIN: 0px } Lorem Ipsum";
string output = Regex.Match(input, @"\w+\s*{.*?}").Value;
System.Console.WriteLine(output); // P { MARGIN: 0px }
```

Comment: `{}` are regex special characters, remember to escape them

Comment: @Isaac - being that the braces don't contain something like `{3}` or `{3,4}`, I don't think it is strictly necessary to escape them (java.util.regex being a notable exception to that, in which escaping would be required).

Comment: @Isaac It may be different in other Regex engines, but at least in .NET's, it appears you only need to escape `{}` when it can be interpreted as a quantifier (e.g. `{2,}`).

Comment: Thanks @p.s.w.g but the regex does not work in case: "P {      MARGIN: 0px } Lorem Ipsum"

Comment: "P { 30spaces MARGIN: 0px } Lorem Ipsum"

Comment: @Rakisbro I've tweaked the pattern to accept whitespace characters between the first word characters and the bracket. See my updated answer.